# Hide/show Layout difficulties

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have three subLinearlayout of `RelativeLayout` . i am hide and show programatically all three layout  under the same `RelativeLayout`.

in all above three subLinearlayout first `Linearlayout` content is large as compared to two others. So when ever i show second `LinearLayout` it occupy space of first `LinearLayout` also.

I want to remove occupied space of FirstLinear Layout at time of showing second LinearLayout.

for better understanding i paste my xml layout below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

   <!-- ATC/TCAS/AIRSPACE -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/atcTypeLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/atcType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/atc_incident_type" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Evacuation -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainEvoccutionLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/evocutionLinear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Emergencies /Evacuation"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/editable"
                android:text="Details  "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <!-- Dyanmic check Box -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/secEvoLinear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- Dyanmic check Box -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Evolution layout over and start of collision near miss -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/collisionNearLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/editable"
            android:text="Collision/Near Miss  "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <!-- dynamic creation of check box -->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Guys Help Me..

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: i want to remove occupied space of FirstLinear Layout at time of showing second LinearLayout.

Comment: have you tried using something besides RelativeLayout for your base ViewGroup?

Comment: `android:visibilty="GONE"` // to required view

Comment: Reading my answer back to myself I might have mis-understood the issue you are having. Is it that when you set the visibility property of the first LinearLayout to gone the second LinearLayout to visible, the second LinearLayout doesn't move to the top of the parent?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden it will move to the top but also occupy same space which has occupied by the first linearlayout

Comment: Use a LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout, so when you remove the FirstLayout it also remove the space and move the second layout up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou guys for your response.
I cant believe, i make a silly mistake in my `.java` i make layout `setVisibility` property to `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE` I Am sorry Guys. For Accepting My Answer.
And Thanx again for helping me. :)

Answer (score 0):

When using RelativeLayout you will need to add some additional properties to the children to tell Android how you want them laid out. You have two possible options, RelativeLayout and LinearLayout;

## RelativeLayout

Note that I've missed out your other attributes for brevity, but they should still be included. The critical parts are  the `android:layout_below` attributes. If you don't include them then views are just attached overlapping each other as you have already observed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/atcTypeLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainEvoccutionLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/atcTypeLinear" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/collisionNearLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/mainEvoccutionLinear" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## LinearLayout

The other option is just to use a LinearLayout as the parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/atcTypeLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainEvoccutionLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/collisionNearLinear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```